# JAVA - Android - Create Directory

Tags: java, android, directory

I'm trying to create a directory on Android devices, in the /storage/emulated/0 directory. My current Java code is:

```
package com.magicsoftware.magicdev;
import com.magicsoftware.core.CoreApplication;

import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.File;

public class CreateDirectory{
    public static void Directory(String dirname){
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/NewFolder");
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I am going to pass the name of the new folder from my development program Magic XPA 3.1 to the field dirname. However, at this stage, I am just trying to create a folder called NewFolder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you define the uses-permission what "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" in AndroidMenifest?
Like this:

```
enter code here<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: The File class is only help you to define the file,and make the directory is only use the IOstream.Please forgive my English is poor.

Comment: Yes the permission has been added.

Comment: Then it's a possible that the device dose't support to write for sdcard.You can switch a devide to checking.

Comment: I have switched devices.. I am not trying to write to SDCard I am trying to write to the internal memory..

Comment: I executing you code in my virtual devices,first in ADV,the directory is't created,but I switched to Nox virtual device,the directory has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

- MainActivity.java

  ```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      FileIoDemo.createFolder("Test");
      FileIoDemo.createFile("Test/test13.jpg");
  }
  ```
- FileIoDemo.java

  ```
  private static final String BASE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator;

  public static void createFolder(String folderPath){
      Log.e(TAG,"Folder Path: "+BASE_PATH+folderPath);
      File mydir = new File(BASE_PATH+folderPath);
      if (!mydir.exists())
      {
          Log.e(TAG,"Folder Created? | "+mydir.mkdirs());
      }
      else{
          Log.e(TAG,"Failed | Folder Creation");
      }
  }//end createFolder

  public static void createFile(String filePath) {
      //CREATE FILE
      Log.e(TAG,"File Path: "+BASE_PATH+filePath);
      File file = new File(BASE_PATH+filePath);
      if (!file.exists()) {
          try {
              Log.e(TAG, "File Created? "+file.createNewFile());
          } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Failed | File Creation");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }//end createFile
  ```
- **AndroidManifest.xml**

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```